# Tkinter window opens after code is finished

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just beginning to get the basic funtions of the soundcard python module to work. However I cannot make my tkinter window show up first and wait until I press the run button to exicute the "def run()" code. It always does the "def run()" code first and then opens the window. What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
import soundcard as sc

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Virtual Soundcard")

default_speaker = sc.default_speaker()
default_mic = sc.default_microphone()

def run():

    with default_mic.recorder(samplerate=44100) as mic, \
        default_speaker.player(samplerate=44100) as sp:
        for val in range(100):
            data = mic.record(numframes=None)
            sp.play(data)

RunButton = Button(window, text ="Run", command = run())
RunButton.pack()
RunButton.place(x = 100, y = 250)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `RunButton = Button(window, text ="Run", command = run())` to

```
RunButton = Button(window, text ="Run", command = run)
```

Basically remove the `()` for the command argument, with the `()` your calling the function even before pressing the button, ie, while code execution.

Hope this solved the error. Do let me know if any doubts or errors.

Cheers